# Dynamic DropDownList City,State in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlists, the first is State & the second is City.  I have the State ddl populated, but I would like to populate the City ddl via the selection in the State ddl.  I am using autoPostBack, so it goes through the motion of updating but nothing loads.  I am sure it is in the code behind or in the databind.  This operation seems simple enough, if anyone has any info or a good link on a way to accomplish this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, after the State & city are selected I have a select button that will send the user to a gridview page with all data.  That part of the page I have working and tested.  It is getting the data to pass that is the issue.

I am using Stored Procs, is there a easier way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be better if you post your code that you have tried so far. so that we can help on that direction rather suggesting complete new things that you may not know well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple to do and there are plenty of articles out there with full source code.

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/03/populate-dropdown-based-selection-other.html

If you want to use the Ajax Control Toolkit, there's even a control just for that.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

and there are plenty of other examples using the following Bing search:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+cascading+dropdown&form=CMDTDF&pc=CMDTDF&src=IE-SearchBox

Comment: Thank You for the links friend, however they are very informative, but I was not able to find specific information to progress my project, since it is VB.  Don't misunderstand, your links are helpful... but not exactly what I need.  Do you have any other suggestions?  All help is appreciated.